# JPA insert object if not exists, do nothing if exists

Tags: java, jpa, cascade

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROPERTY_VALUES")
public class PropertyValuesData extends AbstractData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="VAL_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=  {CascadeType.PERSIST} )
    @JoinColumn(name = "VAL_PROP_ID")
    private PropertyData property;

}
```

Persist object:

```
  public void createItem(TYPE item){
            try{
                em=EMFactory.createEntityManager();
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.persist(item);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error("Error while createItem", e);
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }finally {
                if(em!=null)
                    em.close();
            }
        }
```

I have 2 situation:
1) I create new object `PropertyValuesData`, which contain existing property (with id) -> then I want to ONLY add new `PropertyValuesData`
2)  I create new object `PropertyValuesData`, with new property -> then I want to insert also new `PropertyData`.

If I add `CascadeType.PERSIST`, then I can save new property, but for existing property it try insert it again. What should I do to avoid insert again the same property?

Comment: please add a few more lines of code that show how you are writing the entity to the db/entityManager

Answer (score 2):

Try adding additional `CascadeType.MERGE`

Also, remember that `PropertyData` needs to be `Managed` (so in current persistance context, and not detached) in order for it to work. If you use `Detached` entity, sets it `id` to something from the db, this will result can result in `INSERT` not `UPDATE`.

To get it working 100%, simply `SELECT` required `PropertyData` from the db (even by `id` just like you are trying, set it, and then persist `PropertyValuesData`

Comment: @lucas999 check the reminder. You are using detached entity for sure.